# SMS delivery report received handle

Tags: sms, report

We sent SMS in Argentina with claro company with delivery report. claro gives the delivery report, but the status code of the delivery report is 1. Searching over the web, I've found that all delivery reports with status code > 0 are handled as errors.

But claro returns delivery report as received message by the client. But I can't find any software that allow us to handle the status codes, so the software handle as delivery failed, when it was delivered.